# How to get the one parameter from list of items in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have one field in database table with following lines

```
show_email_icon=
show_hits=
feed_summary=
page_title=
show_page_title=1
pageclass_sfx=
menu_image=hd_events.png
secure=0
```

All the stuff is stored as text in one field of mysql table. Now i want to get the menu_image. How can i get that?

Comment: "All the stuff is stored as text in one field of mysql table". Why are you abusing databases so?

Comment: ha ha , actually i am using joomla and it is storing some parameters like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running PHP5.3 or higher, you can use [`parse_ini_string()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_string) which will give you a nice associative array:

```
$str = fetch_from_db();
$array = parse_ini_string($str);
echo $array['menu_image']; // hd_events.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (preg_match('/^menu_image\\s*=\\s*(.*)$/m', $t, $matches)) {
    //the content is $matches[1];
}
```

You should consider having a table with two columns "key" and "value" and then

```
SELECT value from table_name WHERE key = 'menu_image';
```

Comment: I don't have any control over that. WIll your code work if other variables are populated as well . because they may not be empty everytime

Comment: @Mirage yes. It matches only the line that starts with "menu_image". It also allows whitespace around the equals sign. You can remove the two `\\s*` portions do disallow that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need that one value I'd use [Artefacto's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986921/how-to-get-the-one-paramater-from-list-of-items-in-php/2986946#2986946). If you're going to need any others, it's probably best to un-joomla-ify it and turn that string into a map:

```
preg_match_all("/(.*)=(.*)/", $dbString, $matches); 
$settings = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++)
    $settings[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];

// Use $settings['menu_image'] or any of the others
```